# not able to encode the response of ping into string using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, string, swift, encode

I’m doing a simple ping to a given IP address.I need to check whether the response of ping is timeout or proper reply comes from it.

Below is the code where i need to check the response but still not able to encode into string.

Using SimplePing Class ( for reference https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Listings/SimplePing_m.html ) and the function where i need to encode data

```
func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didReceivePingResponsePacket packet: NSData!) {  

 let myPingResponse : NSString! = NSString(bytes: packet.bytes, length: packet.length, encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding

print(myPingResponse)

}
```

myPingResponse is always nil or some junk characters.
What is wrong in the above code.

thanks